# PHP variable setting div <p> text

Tags: php, html

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I've searched around SO and nothing I've come across seems to help me here.

I have a HTML page with a form which passes values to an external PHP page.

```
      <form method="post" action="getContent.php">

            <input type="hidden" name="fromTest" id="fromTest"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="untilTest" id="untilTest"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="latTest" id="latTest"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="longTest" id="longTest"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="search1" id="search1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="search2" id="search2"/>


       <input type="submit" class="sendAll" value="Gather News!">
      </form>
```

These values are then set in the PHP to variables in SESSION

```
  $_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST;
  $search1 = $_SESSION['post-data']["search1"];
  $search2 = $_SESSION['post-data']["search2"];

  $until = $_SESSION['post-data']["untilTest"];
  $since = $_SESSION['post-data']["from"];
  $lat = $_SESSION['post-data']["latTest"];
  $long = $_SESSION['post-data']["longTest"];
```

This all works great and for the function it was made, everything is working perfectly.

I've got a header in my HTML of which I want the text inside of the div to be the value of $search1.

The feed1MainHeader div is completely in the HTML page and has no current links to PHP.

```
  <div id="feed1MainHeader">
  <p>test<p>
  </div>
```

after the external php page is called and goes back to my html page, I need the header

value to = my first search term.

Any idea how I can do this easily?

Comment: You are not setting any sessions. Do it like this: `$_SESSION['post-data']["search1"] = $_POST['search1'];`

Comment: PHP is processed on the server-side, so there principally could be no manipulation of the client-side DOM. You could grab the values using JavaScript (jQuery would be the easiest) and submit it. Something like this: `$('#yourFormID').submit(function() { $('#hiddenInput').val($('#feed1MainHeader').html()); });`.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit of the code.

$_SESSION['post-data'] = $_POST; 

This is just above my php snippet. I'm pretty sure it does the same?

Comment: @AlistairNorris Correct update your question though.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks but it seems to have an issue with the page refresh that happens with I submit the form to the php.

Answer (score 1):

You can output data stored in session with

```
echo $_SESSION['post-data']['search1']
```

where you need to first search string to appear.

Comment: Sorry my fault, missed a part of my SESSIONS code. Thanks though!

Comment: Thank you for those who is minusing my answer, but I've been writing it when there were no comments yet, and the question was not edited yet.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to say. Any idea how to fix my issue?

Comment: What is to be displayed after form submitting?